# How to get distinct values of concat of 2 columns in Mongodb Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in MongoDb with following

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5756b0rrffac18767"),
 "year" : "1992",
 "initial" : "A",
  "name" : "test"

}

/* 2 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5756b0ffac18767"),
 "year" : "1992",
 "initial" : "B",
  "name" : "test"
}

 /* 3 */
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5756b0ffwwac18767"),
 "year" : "1993",
 "initial" : "A",
  "name" : "test1"
}

/* 4 */
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5756b0ffacee767"),
 "year" : "1992",
 "initial" : "A",
  "name" : "test"
}
```

I need to get the following results like

```
1992-A
1992-B
```

I need to find the distinct of concatenated columns(year and initial) where name="test"

So far, I tried like

```
public List<MyNames> getYears(String name) {
   TypedAggregation<MyNames> agg = Aggregation.newAggregation( MyNames.class,
            project("id","year", "initial"),
            match(Criteria.where("name").is(name))
            group("year")

        ); 

        AggregationResults<MyNames> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, MyNames.class);
        List<MyNames> resultList = result.getMappedResults();
     return resultList;
  }
```

MyNames

```
@Document
```

public class MyNames implements Serializable{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5763434erertr33331L;

@Id
private String id;
private int year;
private String name;
private String initial;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getYear() {
    return year;
}
public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getInitial() {
    return initial;
}
public void setInitial(String initial) {
    this.initial = initial;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MyNames [id=" + id + ", year=" + year + ", name=" + name + ", initial=" + initial + "]";
 }
}
```

This is not working.. Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Could you add the MyNames class declaration to the question?

Comment: @AndriySimonov: I have added the MyNames class declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. Please change the collection name accordingly.

Included the hyphen between year and initial.

```
public Boolean aggregateYearCollection(String name) {

        MongoOperations mongoOperations = getMongoConnection();

        MatchOperation match = new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("name").is(name));
        ProjectionOperation project = Aggregation.project("year", "initial").andExpression("concat(year, '-', initial)").as("yearAndInitial");
        Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, project, Aggregation.group("yearAndInitial"));

        System.out.println(aggregate.toString());

        AggregationResults<YearCollection> yearCollectionAggregate = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregate, "yearcoll", YearCollection.class);

        if (yearCollectionAggregate!=null) {
            System.out.println("Output ====>" + yearCollectionAggregate.getRawResults().get("result"));
            System.out.println("Output ====>" + yearCollectionAggregate.getRawResults().toMap());
        }

        return true;

    }
```

**Output:-**

```
Output ====>[ { "_id" : "1992-A"} , { "_id" : "1992-B"}]
Output ====>{serverUsed=127.0.0.1:27017, waitedMS=0, result=[ { "_id" : "1992-A"} , { "_id" : "1992-B"}], ok=1.0}
```

Aggregate API doesn't give you the list. However, you can get the list of ids by iterating the data.

```
Iterator<YearCollection> yearCollectionIterator = yearCollectionAggregate.iterator();

List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();

while(yearCollectionIterator.hasNext()) {
    valueList.add(yearCollectionIterator.next().getId());
}
```

Comment: Thanks..how do I get the output as List?

Comment: Updated the answer to get the list of ids. It should give you "[1992-A, 1992-B]".

Comment: I am getting getMongoConnection(); as undefined function. What is the package I need to import?

Comment: Getconnection depends on your context. I have this. I hope you have your context set for mongo.
public MongoOperations getMongoConnection() {

  return (MongoOperations) new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringMongoConfig.class)
    .getBean("mongoTemplate");
 }